# Updating data of charts already instantiated

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am using the [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_multiple_charts) and i need to update a map that is already instantiated as a map worth actually want when you click the refresh button the data inside of a map.

Today I am doing in the following way:

```
var dataGraf = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(parsVal);
var chart = document.getElementById('curve_chart');
chart.draw(dataGraf);
```

But nothing happens. For i instantiate my map i used the following commands:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(parsVal);
  var options = {
    title: 'Membros x Visitantes',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };
 var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
 chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

How can i do to update, just when I click the button. Remembering that my 'ataGraf' has my array with the new values.

I did a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vh5Lk3xj/) to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first...
`google.charts.load` & `setOnLoadCallback` should only be called once per page load
you can also include the `callback` in the `load` statement

next, by saving a reference to the original `chart`, you can animate from one dataset to another

on the button click, create `data` and call `draw`

also recommend *not* adding event handlers directly in html tags

see following working snippet, the data is "swapped" on each button click...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    // draw first chart
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Data', 'Membros', 'Visitantes'],
      ['1', 4, 6],
      ['2', 5, 7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      animation: {
        startup: true,
        duration: 1200,
        easing: 'linear'
      },
      title: 'Membros x Visitantes',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    // draw same chart with new data on button click
    var newData = null;
    document.getElementById('chart_button').addEventListener('click', drawNewChart, false);
    function drawNewChart() {
      // switch between newData and data on each click
      if (newData === null) {
        newData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Data', 'Membros', 'Visitantes'],
          ['1', 9, 2],
          ['2', 1, 7]
        ]);
        chart.draw(newData, options);
      } else {
        chart.draw(data, options);
        newData = null;
      }
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<button id="chart_button">Atualizar gráficos</button>
<div id="curve_chart"></div>
```